# Wait for element present in Python

Tags: python, selenium, timeout

I got a running code, but sometimes I get timeout in 30 seconds, sometimes in 80 or more (depends on server side), so the point is - how to make my code stop once I can view the element and not to wait until 120 seconds passed?
Well, what I am trying to achieve is stop the code once the element is NOT PRESENTED on the screen:

```
 def isElementPresent(self):
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)
            wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'GETTING NEW IMAGE FROM HOME SYSTEM')))
        except TimeoutException:
            print('Camera Timeout')
```

Comment: What is `'GETTING NEW IMAGE FROM HOME SYSTEM'`? IS the value changed every loop? I'm just curious why you need that loop.

Comment: no, this name is same all the time. just appears and disappears as the camera changes image

Comment: I can't believe that sometimes you get timeout in 30 or 80 sec. When it enters the loop, it will wait for the element for 120 sec. If it found the element, it will break the `while` loop immediately. Otherwise, it will print 'Camera Timeout' and then go to next loop, and wait for the element for 120 sec. again. The point is the timeout error is always at 120 sec. But the time to break the loop depends on how long does it take to find the element.

Comment: that's correct, I don't want to wait for 120 secs all the time, because it might take less, but the program still waits.

Comment: Where do you call `isElementPresent`? Can you show more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the while loop. Just use the WebDriverWait

```
def isElementPresent(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'GETTING NEW IMAGE FROM HOME SYSTEM')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print('The element appears')
    try:
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'GETTING NEW IMAGE FROM HOME SYSTEM')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print('The element does not disappear')
```

Comment: Tried this, still waits for 120 secs, however the element has gone before that time

Comment: I'm sorry. Do you wait until the element disappears?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I wait until I see the element. then I wait until it is gone, yes

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), try the `visibility_of_element_located` condition:

```
def isElementPresent(self):
    while True:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'GETTING NEW IMAGE FROM HOME SYSTEM')))
            break
        except TimeoutException:
            print('Camera Timeout')
            pass
```